# can I use pipes | in R, not %>%

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe

This has probably been asked but I can't find it. In R, I want to use the | pipe instead of %>%.

I'm used to Linux, and it would be me happy if I could do like this with dplyr or something similar.

Is it possible to use this pipe operator?

```
df | filter(state == "New York")
```

Comment: You can define your own operator that will behave like `%>%`.

Comment: What you'll do for OR in that case?

Comment: `|` has a specific meaning in R, as the OR logical operator. While you could redefine it to the pipe if you wish, it is inadvisable to do so. Rather, accept that different languages mean different syntax.

Comment: agree with Phil -- overloading `|` is a bad idea. if you're really married to the vertical bad, you could define an infix operator `%|%` instead (in fact I believe there's at least one magrittr alternative the already does so)

Comment: The readability and comparability of your code would suffer, therefore in my opinion you should use %>% = shift+ctrl+m.

Comment: Alright, I can live with shirt+ctrl+m. Thank you.

Comment: You need to be aware that `%>%` doesn't act like a pipe in Linux (where each component is a separate process, running simultaneously).  It's useful to use different syntax since it behaves differently.

Comment: I believe some of the commenters confuse with older R versions. magrittr pipe, `%>%`, is not what you're asking about. Native R pipe, `|>`, was added only in R4.0.0 (https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html)  and I know of at least one place it succeeds where the old magrittr pipe fails:  https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4831#issuecomment-738557523

Comment: @OfekShilon the base R pipe is not implemented until version 4.1, scheduled for sometime later this year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be misleading to use the same symbol as  in UNIX since the magrittr pipe is not equivalent to UNIX pipes but that aside any of these give the same result using the built in BOD data frame.

#2 defines an alias for `%>%` .

#3 does too redefining the built in `|` which it clobbers -- not recommended although we try to limit the damage by removing it after use. #3a is a cleaner version of #3 which only defines | locally,   Also we could define it at the top of a function in which case its scope would only be within the body of the function so it cannot do damage globally.

#4 only works in the development version of R.  See `?"|>"`  Note that it is not equivalent to magrittr's `%>%` although it works in a subset of situations where magrittr pipes work.

#5 is the bizarro pipe (google it). It only requires base R and just uses ordinary R syntax in a clever way.

```
library(dplyr)

# 1
BOD %>% filter(Time > 3)

# 2
`%|%` <- `%>%`
BOD %|% filter(Time > 3)

# 3 - not recommended
`|` <- `%>%`
BOD | filter(Time > 3)
rm(`|`) # remove to limit damage

# 3a - redefine | locally only
with(list(`|` = `%>%`), BOD | filter(Time > 3))

# 4 - needs development version of R
BOD |> filter(Time > 3)

# 5 - bizzaro pipe
BOD ->.; filter(., Time > 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI the [next version of R](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/11/magrittr-2-0-is-here/) will natively have a pipe - `|>`